# How do I get untranslated data when the user views a page in Google Translate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-translate, content-script

My extension use content-scripts to grab data from some pages.
But, sometimes users use *Google Translate* on the page and I need original data.

How can I get it?  The content-script grabs translated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the original (untranslated) version:

1. Get its address from the translate-address input:
   [image: Address bar]
2. Load that address in a hidden iframe.
3. Grab the data you want from your new hidden iframe using [the usual methods for dealing with iframes in Google-Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension+iframe?sort=votes).

If the translated page has been modified by AJAX, the AJAX additions aren't available in the "Original" version, but Google-translate doesn't translate these either (for now) -- so just grab the AJAXed changes directly, from the translated-page iframe.